# how row Max record database sqlite in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i want show Max record in database sqlite in android
But there is an error?
Please help me

```
 public Day show_Day_Hazine_Max()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT did,MAX(day),hazine FROM Day",null);

    if(cursor == null)
    {
        return  null;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst() ;
        Day day = new Day();

        day.setDid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("did")));
        day.setDay(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")));
        day.setHazine(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("hazine")));

    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return day;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is thrown because in your results there is no column with name `day`.
You must alias the aggregated column `MAX(day)` to `day`:

```
SELECT did,MAX(day) day,hazine FROM Day
```